# Gradle 'exit' in a shell script

Tags: shell, gradle, pipe, sh, cat

I want to build a package by Gradle (3.2.1) using a script.

The script (`hoge.sh`) is

```
#!/bin/sh
gradle build
echo "hello"
```

`./hoge.sh` works and prints "hello".

However, `cat hoge.sh | /bin/sh -s` stops at `gradle build`. 
The build looks successful but the process never prints "hello".

How can I fix `hoge.sh` to run by  `cat hoge.sh | /bin/sh -s` correctly??

If I run  `cat hoge.sh | /bin/sh -i`, it returns,

```
sh-4.2$ #!/bin/sh
sh-4.2$ gradle build
###gradle information###
sh-4.2$ exit
```

For information, using Gradle 2.1, the `exit` comes at last (after `echo "hello"`).

```
sh-4.2$ #!/bin/sh
sh-4.2$ gradle build
###gradle information###
sh-4.2$ echo "hello"
hello
sh-4.2$ exit
```

How can I avoid the `exit` **by Gradle** and let `echo "hello"` survive?
add something to the second line `gradle build` ? or to `cat hoge.sh | /bin/sh`?

Comment: What is for you need to run `./gradlew` before `./gradlew build`? Why don't you call a build at once?

Comment: I thought ```./gradlew``` is for those who has no gradle environment, which is installation.  and even if I use ```./gradlew build```, its exit finishes the script...(I want to add some lines after ```./gradlew build``` as well)

Comment: anyway to clarify, I modified my question. Thank  you!

Comment: Does `gradle build` consume its standard input? Try `gradle build </dev/null` to force it to leave stdin alone.

Comment: (Tangentially also, avoid the [useless `cat`;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat) `sh -s <hoge.sh`.)